# Decrement with a value other than one?

Tags: android

How would I make the following code decrease the alpha value faster; i.e. a value greater than one, per tick?

```
   @Override
   public boolean tick() {
       if ( level.alpha > 0 )
           --level.alpha;

   [...]

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`level.alpha -= 2;`

Surely you've seen `+=` or `-=` before?

Comment: Ah, was just typing it incorrectly... kept getting compiler errors, was blatantly confused... thank you for tolerating my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 level.alpha-=n;
```

with n your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you don't want the value of your variable to go negative, which would happen if it starts at 1 and you subtract a number greater than one.

This will set your variable to 0 if it would have become negative:

```
level.alpha = Math.max(0, level.alpha - 2);
```

Or equivalently:

```
level.alpha -= 2;
if (level.alpha < 0) { level.alpha = 0; }
```